# Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' in Travis CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

I have the following `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - "2.0.0"
# uncomment this line if your project needs to run something other than `rake`:
before_script:
  - psql -c "create database dummy_test;" -U postgres
  - psql -c "CREATE USER dummy WITH PASSWORD 'dummy';" -U postgres
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rspec spec
```

When I try running it in Travis CI, I get this error message:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'
```

I've been trying different approaches for hours. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to migrate your test db when you are calling db:test:prepare?

Comment: It's based on the code I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591599/rake-dbmigration-not-working-on-travis-ci-build). Honestly, I have no idea why this is failing, so I've tried just mimicking what worked for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got it working.

The issue was that the application was a dummy application buried within `spec/dummy`, so running `rake db:migrate` wouldn't work from the root directory. In order to fix this, I followed the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465754/how-to-manage-migrations-for-a-rails-engine-dummy-app). Edit the Rakefile to point to `spec/dummy` and then run rspec tests:

```
APP_RAKEFILE = File.expand_path("../spec/dummy/Rakefile", __FILE__)
load 'rails/tasks/engine.rake'
require "rspec/core/rake_task"

task :default => :spec

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |spec|
  spec.pattern = 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
  # spec.rspec_opts = ['-cfs --backtrace']
end
```